# Changing Child Index of MovieClips based on their Y Position?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, removechild, addchild

I'm writing a game with Flash CS5/AS 3.0 that tries to simulate depth of field by drawing all the relevant Movie Clips based on their Y position in ascending order, i.e. things lower on the stage overlap things higher on the stage.  A MovieClip with a Y position of 10 would therefore need to have a lower index compared to a MovieClip with a Y position of 20, so the second one gets drawn on top of the first.

I wrote a quick and dirty function just to test this.  During the trace, I've noticed that the truck's index hits 0 when I go near the top of the stage, but if I go too far up it will completely disappear from the stage.  Trace then starts generating this error:

> **ArgumentError: Error #2025:** The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
>           at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
>           at EICT::Game/ReorganizeDisplayIndexes()
>           at EICT::Game/loop()

theTruck is a MovieClip of the player controlled vehicle
Enemies, Cones, Rocks are all arrays which contain MovieClips

None of them have event listeners.

```
    private function ReorganizeDisplayIndexes(): void
    {
        var drawableObjects:Array = new Array();
        drawableObjects.push(theTruck);
        drawableObjects = drawableObjects.concat(Enemies, Rocks, Bushes);
        drawableObjects.sortOn("y", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
        drawableObjects.reverse();
        trace(collisionLayer.getChildIndex(theTruck));
        for (var a:int = collisionLayer.numChildren - 1; a >= 0; a--)
        {
            collisionLayer.removeChildAt(a);
        }
        for (var i:int = 0; i < drawableObjects.length; i++)
        {
            collisionLayer.addChild(drawableObjects[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You don't need to remove the child first. When you use `addChild()` on an object, it is automatically re-added to the next highest depth.

That said, you'll just need to do something like this:

```
drawableObjects.sortOn("y");

for each(var i:DisplayObject in drawableObjects)
{
    if(i.parent)
        i.parent.addChild(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've mucked around with it and it turns out that this bit of code isn't even responsible for making the truck disappear in the first place.  I'm still going to use this method instead though.

Answer (score 0):

Use setChildIndex instead of removing and re-adding:

```
for (var a:int = collisionLayer.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    collisionLayer.setChildIndex(drawableObjects[i], i);
}
```

Also, it's a bit wasteful to first order the sort in descending and then reversing the array. Sort it ascending to begin with!